# How to replace all the <li> elements of an <ul> using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I replace all the `li` of a `ul` in JQuery, I don't want to add any new item to the list by using `append` rather I want a new list with new `li` elements in the same `ul`.

I have tried

```
for (index = 0; index < users.length; ++index) {
$('#users').replaceChild(users[index].UserName, $('#users').childNodes[index]);
}
```

#HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin:auto">
    <h2 class="text-success">Users</h2>
    <ul id="users" style="list-style:none"></ul>
</div>
```

but it only add the last element of the Array to the `ul`,
how to create a new `ul` when every time I got a new list?

Comment: $("#yourUL").html('') before appending?

Comment: that was my practice code that I have tried so far.

Comment: add your html also

Comment: Add your html which you are getting now and what you are expecting result form the raw html. Add live example using jsfiddle

Comment: please see the updated question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you include an example of your array. I made a snippet, hope it helps.

```js
var array = ["New li 1", "New li 2", "New li 3"];

$('#load').click(function(){

  $('#list').empty();
  $.each(array, function( key, value ) {
    $('#list').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>Old li 1</li>
  <li>Old li 2</li>
  <li>Old li 3</li>
</ul>

<button id="load">Load array</button>
```

Comment: You got the point, ` $('#list').empty();` was the trick here.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery `.replaceWith()` function.

simply use the following code

```
$('#users').replaceWith( "<li>New Item</li>" );
```

[Refer this article](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) .

Comment: can you explain how `$('#users').replaceWith( "<li>New Item</li>" );` going to create a list of new `,li>`,?

Comment: If you can read this article (http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) it clearly explains the theory with example

Comment: if did you get the point of `replaceWith()` then answer the question according to it's requirement if you can...